# How can I save a current snapshot of my app before I rotate?

Tags: java, android, orientation

Is there a way I can save the current snapshot of my app before it gets destroyed (when it gets rotated):

I know I can save all my data in

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {}
```

But is there something simpler because I have a lot of data that would need to get saved.

Comment: Well, what kind of data do you have? How much simpler do you need?!

Comment: i have 12 textviews in my activity. maybe im being lazy. im just looking to see if i have any other options.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use 
buildDrawingCache();
Bitma b=getDrawingCache();

Then you can use Canvas to draw the Bitmap and rotate it.

At last, destroyDrawingCache().

that's it.

Comment: He doesn't mean a literal snapshot.  (I don't think).  He means a snapshot of the data.